# Binding library error 'The Java type could not be found' of a public interface

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I'm creating a binding library of a 3rd party sdk.

When building the project, I get the following warning:

`The Java type 'x.x.UrlLookupService.ResultNotifier<R, x.x.RpRestException>' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)`

The original Java code:

```
public class UrlLookupService {
        ...
        public interface ResultNotifier<R, E extends AbstractRestException> {
            void finish(@Nullable R var1);
    
            void fail(@NonNull E var1);
        }
}
```

The auto-generated code:

```
public abstract partial class AbstractRestException : global::Java.Lang.Exception
```

With 3 `protected` constructors, as in the original Java code.

```
// Metadata.xml XPath interface reference: path="/api/package[@name='x.x']/interface[@name='UrlLookupService.ResultNotifier']"
[Register ("x/x/UrlLookupService$ResultNotifier", "", "x.x.UrlLookupService/IResultNotifierInvoker")]
[global::Java.Interop.JavaTypeParameters (new string [] {"R", "E extends x.x.AbstractRestException"})]
public partial interface IResultNotifier : IJavaObject, IJavaPeerable {
    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='x.x']/interface[@name='UrlLookupService.ResultNotifier']/method[@name='fail' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='E']]"
    [Register ("fail", "(x/x/AbstractRestException;)V", "GetFail_x_x_AbstractRestException_Handler:x.x.UrlLookupService/IResultNotifierInvoker, XSdk")]
    void Fail (global::Java.Lang.Object p0);

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='x.x']/interface[@name='UrlLookupService.ResultNotifier']/method[@name='finish' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='R']]"
    [Register ("finish", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", "GetFinish_Ljava_lang_Object_Handler:x.x.UrlLookupService/IResultNotifierInvoker, XSdk")]
    void Finish (global::Java.Lang.Object p0);
}
```

Whenever I encountered this type of warning, it was caused by either obfuscated classes or by access specifiers, which I was able to correct via `Metadata.xml`, but it doesn't seem to be the case here. The classes are public and the interface seems to be generated successfully.

Why am I receiving this message?

This affects other critical classes being removed in `java-resolution-report.log`, so I can't just `remove-node`